# Seed, Random number, and bound using java.uitl.Random

Tags: java, random

(1)So I first thought a seed is something that starts the random number as the book says "s a number used to initialize a random number generator".So random numbers should start with seed, which is not the case.Please explain.

(2) Using seed and java API java.util.Random, I want to generate 10 random numbers with bound 300-1000.However, the following code giving me all same numbers:

```
import java.util.*;
public class RandomClassTest {

public static void main(String [] args) {
    Random rd = new Random(300);
    int randInt = rd.nextInt(1000-300)+300;
    int count = 1;

    while( count <= 10) {
        System.out.println(randInt);
        count++;
        }
     }  
   }   

My output:
743
743
743
743
743
743
743
743 
743
743 
// all the time same output without any variation
```

Comment: Your loop is always printing `randInt`, you're not recalculeting it.

Comment: You're not changing the number, place randInt = rd.nextInt(1000-300)+300; inside your loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A seed is **not necessarily** the first number in the sequence of random-numbers generated by a PRNG. The seed is only used to initialize the random-number generator, which is **pseudo** random. Basically the "pseudo" means that numbers aren't random at all, but simply looking random. They're just generated by a (more or less) complex function from previously generated numbers. The purpose of the seed is to be used as a starting point, from which the PRNG can start to create numbers. Whether the sequence starts with the seed as first output-number or doesn't is rather implementation-specific, though for simple security-reasons it's recommendable not to start with the seed as first output-number.

Note that two PRNG using the same code and seed produce the exact same sequence of numbers - there might be some coincidental sideeffects that alter the result though.

As an example for what a seed is used for in a PRNG, take a look at this implementation of [XORShift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift), which is a rather simple PRNG:

```
class XORShift{
    private int x, y, z, w;

    public XORShift(int seed){
        x = seed;
        y = seed >>> 20 | seed << 12;
        z = seed >>> 10 | seed << 22;
        w = seed >>> 25 | seed << 7;
    }

    public int next() {
        int t = x;
        t ^= t << 11;
        t ^= t >> 8;
        x = y; y = z; z = w;
        w ^= w >> 19;
        w ^= t;
        return w;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the seed is used to initialize the state-variables of the generator, which are then altered in each step and combined to produce a new random number. The above algorithm is just a translation of the example-code on wikipedia into java, you'll find pretty much the same code in c/c++ there.

Answer (score 0):

You been printing the same number ten times. You loop should have been like this.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Random rd = new Random(300);    
    int count = 1;
    while( count <= 10) {
        int randInt = rd.nextInt(1000-300)+300;
        System.out.println(randInt);
        count++;
    }         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so there's a few problems with your code.

**First:**

there really isn't a thing such as "pure random" but only "pseudo random" and what this means is that all random numbers are actually just a sequence of numbers that are predetermined and what the seed does is it essentially tells the code where the start the long list of numbers. For example

```
1 
10 
4 
5 
2 
7 
3 
29 
8 
2
```

is my "list" of random numbers.

A seed of 1 means I'll take the first number: 1 then my next "random" number will be 10 then 4.. if I have a seed of 2 then I'll start from 10 then 4 then 5 etc etc.

Generally speaking you will populate your random seed with Time.Now to get different results every time you run your code. Right now, if you try to run your code time and time again.. you will get the **SAME** number every time. Now, that's not very random is it?

**Second:**

The next bug in your code is that int `randInt = rd.nextInt(1000-300)+300;` is outside of your loop and that is the code that is actually getting the next "random" number.

You will need to put that line into your loop to get different random numbers.

Comment: Why if you have a seed 2 it starts from 10,not 7 as it looks next random number in your list is 7.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable randInt is with the same value for all iterations.
You should put it in the loop body:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Random rd = new Random(300);
    int count = 1;

    while( count <= 10) {
        int randInt = rd.nextInt(1000-300)+300;
        System.out.println(randInt);
        count++;
        }
     }  
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not changing the number, place `randInt = rd.nextInt(1000-300)+300;` inside your loop

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this with puting `int randInt = rd.nextInt(1000-300)+300;` inside while loop:

```
   int count = 1;
   Random rd = new Random(300);
   while( count <= 10) {
    int randInt = rd.nextInt(1000-300)+300;
    System.out.println(randInt);
    count++;
    }
 }
```

Comment: see the answer @Rafsan Mobasher